recaptcha__en.js: Uncaught TypeError: qF is not a function
I am recently facing problem with reCAPTCHA Enterprise.
On every form where it is implemented i get this error:
Uncaught TypeError: qF is not a function
    at recaptcha__en.js:601:176
    at Array.<anonymous> (recaptcha__en.js:68:221)
    at recaptcha__en.js:599:379
    at recaptcha__en.js:1034:261

There were no code or database changes, it is Magento environment with Hyva theme.
Tried going back with codebase and backuped database and error still exist.

What version of Magento are you using?  Do you get a "your reCaptcha reputation is too low." warning when your contact form is submitted?  I've had a similar issue reported today and am wondering if there's been a Google update.

It is 2.4.5-p2 version but problem was solved by RichardB. It is somehow connected to https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/release-notes#March_28_2024 this release of Google reCAPTCHA.

I just had the same issue and for me the answer was the same as this question.
Basically, my knockout code had self = this; in the initialisation.  Making this var self = this; fixes it.
I suspect Google must have released an update which means using self as a global variable is causing conflicts.
I'd perhaps search any non-core form extensions for the term self = this; to see if that is also the case for you.

Facing same issue in .Net core + Knockout JS web app. Is there a resolution for this from recaptcha end, instead of modifying web app code which was working fine so far.

I had this problem recently in my magento 2.4.7 application
capture 1
capture error
I follow the advice from "RichardB", removing or adding "var" in the declarations that contain "self = this" in my custom modules was enough to solve the problem.
capture 2
